# MQL4 Terminal Maxbars

Tags: terminal, mql4

My terminal is set max bars in chart of 90 so that only the data I need is loaded.

When in the EA's code, `int iMaxBars = TERMINAL_MAXBARS;` returns 11.

Are these not supposed to be the same? Is there a different function I should use to return the 90?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try `int result=(int)ChartGetInteger(0,CHART_VISIBLE_BARS,0);`
but of couse it depends on what you need. If you have less bars in history - probably the result is underestimated, if you shift the chart to allow space on the right-hand side, it may also decrease the result